# WinRM Listener Resets on Startup

Tags: powershell, azure, certificate, virtual-machine, winrm

I have an **Azure VM** running Windows Server 2016 (64-bit, 14393.1593).

It has some **WinRM** listeners on it, one for HTTP and one for HTTPS.

When I restart the machine, the **HTTPS** listener resets itself to an old configuration (hostname and thumbprint).  With this, it also re-creates the corresponding server certificate.

I delete the certificate and the HTTPS listener.  Using PowerShell, I recreate the listener with the desired hostname and thumbprint.  The thumbprint corresponds to a certificate on the server that behaves as expected (the desired certificate isn't deleted on machine restart).

Everything works until the next machine restart, where I find that the old HTTPS listener is back, with the old hostname and thumbprint.  The old thumbprint corresponds to the old certificate that I had deleted, but the old certificate came back from the grave.

Why is my HTTPS listener resetting itself?

---

**Steps for Configuring WinRM**

In Powershell, I execute the following commands.

`winrm e winrm/config/listener;` - Enumerates the listeners.

`winrm delete winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS;` - Deletes the HTTPS listener.

I then manually delete the old server certificate using either the MMC or IIS manager.  I also get the thumbprint for the correct certificate.

I then execute the following PowerShell.

`winrm create winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS '@{Hostname="MyIPAddress";CertificateThumbprint="MyThumbprint";port="5986"}';` - Creates a new HTTPS listener.

Comment: Could you update the question with the steps you take to configure WinRM?

Comment: Question updated with configuration steps.

Comment: Hi @srsedate. Have you found a solution to this problem? I'm getting it too.

Comment: @gvdm Unfortunately no, I ultimately had to re-create the server.  I'm also not able to re-produce the issue voluntarily, so I'm currently not able to pave a path forward for this one.